# How to connect to Statistics Canada JSON from R

Tags: json, r

I'm trying to connect to an online database through R, which can be found here:
http://open.canada.ca/data/en/dataset/2270e3a4-447c-45f6-8e63-aea9fe94948f

How would I be able to load the data table into R and then be able to simply change the table name in my code to access other tables? I'm not particularly concerned with what language I need to use (JSON, JSOn-LD, XML).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know the URLs for each of the datasets a similar question can be found here:

[Download a file from HTTPS using download.file()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23028760/download-a-file-from-https-using-download-file)

For this it becomes:

```
library(RCurl)

URL <-  "http://www.statcan.gc.ca/cgi-bin/sum-som/fl/cstsaveascsv.cgi?filename=labr71a-eng.htm&lan=eng"
x <- getURL(URL)
URLout <- read.csv(textConnection(x),row.names=NULL)
```

I obtained the URL by right-clicking the access button and copying the address.

I had to declare `row.names=NULL` as the number of columns in the first row is not equal to the number of columns elsewhere, thus `read.csv` assumes row names [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595673/read-csv-row-names). I'm not sure if the URL to these datasets would change when they are updated, but this isn't a really convenient way to get this data. The JSON doesn't seem to be much better for intuitively being able to change datasets.

At least this way you could create a list of URLs and perform the following:

```
URL <- list(getURL("http://www.statcan.gc.ca/cgi-bin/sum-som/fl/cstsaveascsv.cgi?filename=labr71a-eng.htm&lan=eng"),
            getURL("http://www.statcan.gc.ca/cgi-bin/sum-som/fl/cstsaveascsv.cgi?filename=labr72-eng.htm&lan=eng"))

URLout <- lapply(URL,function(x) read.csv(textConnection(x),row.names=NULL,skip=2))
```

Again I don't like having to declare `row.names=NULL` and when I look at the file I'm not seeing the discrepant number of columns, however this will at least get the file into the R environment for you. It may take some more work to perform the operation over multiple URLs.

In a further effort to obtain useful `colnames`:

```
URL <-  "http://www.statcan.gc.ca/cgi-bin/sum-som/fl/cstsaveascsv.cgi?filename=labr71a-eng.htm&lan=eng"
x <- getURL(URL)
URLout <- read.csv(textConnection(x),row.names=NULL, skip=2)
```

The arguement `skip = 2` will skip the first 2 rows when reading in the CSV, and will yield some header names. Because the headers are numbers an X will be placed in front. Row 2 in this case will have the value "number" in the second column. Unfortunately it appears this data was intended for use within excel, which is really sad.

Comment: It does import the table, but it looks like there would be no easy way to import data by being able to pick a table name, since it's not in the URL. Thanks!

Comment: Yea, kind of a pain I was hoping for that too. Further they have really poor names for their CSVs. labr71a-eng, now I'd be curious if they have some kind of naming convention documentation that might help you sort out what lives where. I checked the meta data files there too. Didn't really yield a lot of information.

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to download the CSV into some directory that you have access to.

2) Use "read.csv", or "read_csv", or "fread" to read that csv file into R.

```
yourTableName<-read.csv("C:/..../canadaDataset.csv")
```

3) You can name that csv into whatever object name you want.

Comment: Yes, but then that would mean I have to download the tables individually. I'm looking for a way to create list of tables I want to have, and then execute the script so I can pull all the tables at once directly from the site. Also, if the data changes I'd have to re-pull all tables..which wouldn't be convenient

Comment: Since that's a web form (?cgi), I'm not entirely sure how you can pull all the tables at once from the site. If the file was located on the site "statcan.gc.ca/dataset.csv", then that's an entirely different story...